# Send a function from front-end ( website ) to back-end to return data into front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm making a website that goes on yahoo-finance and pulls data from there into MongoDB then displays it onto the front end. I can manually do it, but I was wondering if it's possbile to let users somehow tell the backend to fetch the data FOR ANY STOCK THEY WANT ( besides the ones that are already there ), store it onto MongoDB and display the data back onto front end?

I'm not very experienced with node.js/express.js/MongoDB - so I'm not sure if it's possible.
But all I'd need the code to do is change "tsla" ( from the code below that I'm using to fetch stock data ) into whatever stock symbol the user enters and add it into the index.js node file so that it can be stored onto the database and updated.

Here's how it'd work:

1. User types in stock name
2. If user clicks "search" on the front end - it should make the program go into backend code, and add a new function to fetch the data for a stock they want to see ( same one as below, just switch "tsla" for whatever stock name they type in - I'm thinking that I could use props to push that function in React with {stock_name} instead of "tsla".. is it a good idea?).
3. The function should add a new entry to MongoDB and display it back to front end ( I have this functionality working already for stocks I manually enter )

as of now I have to manually search for a stock name that I want to display and store it onto my MongoDB then fetch it and display it into my front end... how would you guys go about it? **what should I learn to be able to do it?** Would react props be able to accomplish this ?

TL;DR **make front end (react/html/js) add a function into backend node index.js based on user's input**

I know it's probably not the easiest task - but any tips would be greatly appreaciated. I will give you thumbs up for good suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance !
this is the function I want added - I only need to change "tsla" to whatever stock symbol the user types in

```
async function tsla() {

    /// go on yahoo finance and fetch data from class name's that are holding this data 
    const html = await request.get(
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/"
        );

    const $ = await cheerio.load(html);
    /// store the data as constants
    const Price = $('[class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"]').text();
    const Symbol = $('[class="D(ib) Fz(18px)"]').text();
    const PercentChange = $('fin-streamer[class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)"][data-field="regularMarketChangePercent"]').find('span').text();

    // connect to mongodb and store the data there
    await connectToMongoDB();
        
    const listingModel = new Tsla({
        price: Price, 
        symbol: Symbol, 
        percentChange: PercentChange,
    });
 
    /// update price if it changed since last time 
    await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            symbol: "Tesla (TSLA)",
        }, 
        {
        price: Price, 
        symbol: "Tesla (TSLA)", 
        percentChange: PercentChange,
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        }
        );
        console.log(Price)

    setTimeout(tsla, 30000); // 60,000 == 60 seconds == 1minute // run the function every 30 seconds to check and update price 
}
tsla();
```

https://github.com/szumi112/stockpricesapp

Comment: It wouldn’t “add a function”, the front end would send a query string that the back end would use to do the underlying query and store the data. This is how basically every website works: front end sends data, back end operates on that data.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more ideas I get.. I'm thinking of adding some sort of a if/else function that fetches data from "search bar" and pushes it into back end.. it's probably going to click eventually - for now it's just a thought.. but thank you for commenting, i'll look into queries :)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by an “if/else” function. It might be worth taking a quick step back to figure out some fundamentals: this is literally what web apps with a back end do—consume and process data from the front end. When you fill out a form and hit “Submit”, or as you type in an auto-complete box, apps w/ a back end take that data and do something with it.

Comment: I literally started learning backend with this project - so thank you a lot for sharing your knowledge because so far this seems like black magic to me... you said "consuming and processing data" as well as "queries" - i'll look deeper into it! thank you a lot, really - i was clueless up to this point